# (Discord.py) How can I get the entire embed content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanna get all the embed content(including the image link), I tried this:

```
print(msg.embeds)
```

And that's returning:

```
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E48768CD30>]
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E48768CAF0>]
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E487F04040>]
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E48768CA60>]
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E48768C9D0>]
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000002E487F043A0>]
```

I cant find anything about that on the documentation, only about sending embeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just getting embeds. According to API References, you can't get the whole embed content with one function like `message.content`. You have to get it part by part like [`Embed.title`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.title), [`Embed.description`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.description) and [`Embed.fields`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.fields).

> `Embed.fields` Returns a list of `EmbedProxy` denoting the field contents.
> See add_field() for possible values you can access.
> If the attribute has no value then Empty is returned.

So that means, you can get embed title, description, and fields' name and value. Here's a simple example for this:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title='Example', description='Embed')
embed.add_field(name='field 1 name', value='field 1 value')
embed.add_field(name='field 2 name', value='field 2 value')
```

```
embed.title # returns 'Example'
embed.description # returns 'Embed'
embed.fields # returns a list of fields
embed.fields[0].name # returns 'field 1 name'
embed.fields[0].value # returns 'field 1 value'
embed.fields[1].name # returns 'field 2 name'
embed.fields[1].value # returns 'field 2 value'
```

Comment: Thanks. That should work, I'll also read the pages that you sent.